# Prevent itemView from being added to CompositeView after collection "add"

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a problem with Backbone and Marionette. I have a CompositeView with a collection where people can a comment, this all works nicely, the comment is added and saved to the server but I don't want the view to update and to show the newly added comment. I have tried this:

```
App.Views.CommentsView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: '#article-comment-container',
    itemViewContainer: 'ul',
    itemView: App.Views.CommentView,
    collectionEvents: {
        "add": "modelAdded"
    },
    modelAdded: function(){
        console.log('Please do nothing!');
    }
});
```

But the item is still rendered into the page on top of my modelAdded function being called. Can I prevent that from happening at some point?

In a different scenario I would like new items to be added to the top of the list and not the bottom. Do I have to override the entire appendHtml method achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the collection event `add` simply adds another handler to the queue for that event; it doesn't replace any other events so the default marionette behaviour will still occur.

I assume you're calling the `create` method on the collection to create your new comment model. If this is the case you simply need to set the `silent` option to true. Now the `add` event will not fire and Marionette will not create and render the view for that model. You can do it like this:

```
commentCollection.create(commentModel, {silent: true});
```

As for you second question about prepending, yes I would override `appendHtml` method. Or to keep the method names consistent with what actually happens, create a method called `prependHtml` and then override the `renderItemView` method to call `prependHtml`.

Comment: silent: true! I knew I forgot about something really easy to make this happen. I ended up overriding the appendHtml function for both scenarios but thank you very much for pointing me towards the obvious.